# Are Tor Hidden Service Addresses private by default?

Tags: onion-services, protocol

If I want to configure a Hidden Service but only for personal use and didn't give out its hostname/.onion address to anyone. Can its address still be crawled/known to any third party?

Summary: If no one has a Hidden Service address, then no one will be able to find it and so I don't need to worry about configuring as if its a publicly accessible service?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a hidden service to be private, you need to use authenticated hidden services. On the server side, this is the `HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient` options, and clients will then need to add the `HidServAuth` option to their local configuration. Access to the hidden service will be impossible unless clients have both the address and a valid authentication cookie.

The downside is that it's pretty cumbersome for the clients as there is no integration with the Tor Browser currently.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not private. Hidden services publish contact information (descriptor) to hidden service directories. One of them might be evil, and use the data in a search engine. Also, methods for identifying hidden services have been published, and vulnerabilities have been patched.<sup>1,2</sup> But maybe others haven't.

[1. Biryukov et al. (2013) Trawling for Tor Hidden Services: Detection, Measurement, Deanonymization](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2013/papers/4977a080.pdf%3E)
[2. Jansen et al. 2014 The Sniper Attack: Anonymously Deanonymizing and Disabling the Tor Network](http://www.robgjansen.com/publications/sniper-ndss2014.pdf%3E)